# NetCFSvcUtil, with Generic Collections?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to generate WCF client using NetCFSvcUtil and want it to return List and not Object[] array.
I try with /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 option but it did't work..
Has anyone managed to do it? I managed to manually edit the created class, but it's too much work, because I create proxy class very often during development process..